# O(n) runtime algorithm

Tags: algorithm, performance, big-o, notation

The algorithm below has runtime `O(n)` according to our professor, however I am confused as to why it is not
`O(n log(n))`, because the outer loop can run up to `log(n)` times and the inner loop can run up to `n` times.

```
Algoritme Loop5(n) 
i = 1 
while i ≤ n 
    j = 1 
    while j ≤ i 
       j = j + 1 
    i = i∗2
```

Answer (score 9):

Your professor was right, the running time is `O(n)`.

In the `i`-th iteration of the outer while-loop, when we have `i=2^k` for `k=0,1,...,log n`, the inner while-loop makes `O(i)` iterations. (When I say `log n` I mean the base-2 logarithm `log_2 n`.)

The running time is `O(1+2+2^2+2^3+...+2^k)` for `k=floor(log n)`. This sums to `O(2^{k+1})` which is `O(2^{log n})`. (This follows from the [formula for the partial sum of geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula).)

Because `2^{log n} = n`, the total running time is `O(n)`.

For the interested, here's a proof that the powers of two really sum to what I claim they sum to. (This is a very special case of a more general result.)

*Claim.* For any natural `k`, we have `1+2+2^2+...+2^k = 2^{k+1}-1`.

*Proof.* Note that `(2-1)*(1+2+2^2+...+2^k) = (2 - 1) + (2^2 - 2) + ... + (2^{k+1} - 2^k)` where all `2^i` for `0<i<k+1` cancel out, except for `i=0` and `i=k+1`, and we are left with `2^{k+1}-1`. QED.

Comment: How result is not O(n)?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. It is O(n). :)

Comment: Correct. I'm adding a second explanation [here](http://nopaste.linux-dev.org/?1041307) for clarity's sake

Comment: It should be noted that this is precisely the reason why we usually grow buffers by powers of two: It makes the work needed to repeatedly copy over existing buffer contents `O(N)`, which is much nicer than the `O(N^2)` that is associated with growing a buffer by a constant amount of space.